# Mysql server running only on unix socket

Tags: mysql

I've tried to comment out the port and bind-address directives in the my.cnf to mysql use only unix socket, but in this case the server uses the default port configuration and default bind address. Is there any solution to use the mysql only on unix socket?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok can your explain your ambition? I think mysql need an ip-adress and when you uncomment the line its normal that he use the default ip and port.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to your `my.cnf`:

```
skip-networking
```

This is recommended practice when there is no reason for it to listen on TCP.

Answer (score 1):

By default this line 'SKIP-NETWORKING' is commented

Comment: uncomment it and restart the service

Comment: ohh, yes, but it seemed like the end of a comment, that's why I didn't see it...